# PHP file structure: variables and functions

Tags: php

I have worked in PHP before, but mainly some small touches that actually concern the output HTML. I am more of a front-end guy. Now, I am building a small-scale website that has a lot of duplication in the head, header, and footer but differs a bit in content (*almost* your typical "template" style design). I am not sure how I should handle dependencies in such scenario. I have variables, I have functions, and I have includes and requires. But where goes what?

For instance. I have a `config.php` file that contains a couple of global static variables that are often used (such as `$home` which is the base url - this is necessary for testing locally in subdirectories). I require this config file at the top of each other PHP file. I think that should be sort of alright?

But then: what to do with global variables that change per page. Simple example: Let's say I have this code in `page.php`:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

and header.php looks like this:

```
<header>
    <h1><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>
</header>
```

Is it simply as easy to put the value for that page in `page.php`? Like so:

```
$pageTitle = "I like bananas";
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
```

This concerns me, because if you have a lot of these things - PHP turns ugly: after a while your base PHP file (`page.php`) is cluttered with variables. Not thousands of them, obviously, but I guess it could be around a dozen for my project. Is that a "problem" or is that something that usually happens? If it's not usual, how then should I handle variables in PHP?

And what about functions? For instance, if I want to add a class to a certain item in `header.php`, if a variable is `5` (obviously the real example is more elaborate), I could write a function like so:

```
function checkBananaAmount($int) {
    if ($int == 5) echo 'class="eat-bananas"';
}
```

and call it like so:

```
<div <?php checkBananaAmount($myBanana); ?>></div>
```

The question is, would I put this function in a separate file (similar to Wordpress' `functions.php`, or would I just place it in `header.php`? If the former, does that mean I have to `require "functions.php"` in each page with one of these functions as well?

As you can see I am wondering how the basic structure of PHP projects are: how to sort variables and functions, how to keep things neatly organised and so on, without losing productivity and keeping efficiency.

Comment: This really depends. If a function is needed on EACH page, or a majority of pages, I'd suggest adding it in a central file. If it's used for may be one or two pages, I'd just add it in the actual page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to structure projects, including whether or not to include a framework (can take time to learn, but benefits enormously as project grows).

These days I would not start a php project with a blank slate.

As a front end person, I assume you know frameworks such as angular or knockout.

A good starting point might be a simple framework like Slim http://www.slimframework.com/

And a templating system like Twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Even if you are going the start from scratch method, you should have a good look at PHP The Right Way http://www.phptherightway.com/